# Restore databases from row files

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.1

I do not find the solution alone, hope you could help me.

I have one vm who hacked, rescue mode is activated. I can acces on this machine only via sftp protocol.

Is it possible to import bases from row files.

I have a 9.1 version installed. is it possible to  restore bases from /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/base  on a another instance and vm, by just coping files.

It's worked with my Mysql isntance

I can't use any services from the hacked vm

Answer (score 0):

You mean that somebody took over the machine, but left the database running? Forget about the data and use your backup. You don't know how the data have been modified.

If you can get access via SQL, take a backup with `pg_basebackup` and you can restore that (although I wouldn't use the data).

If you cannot do that, you can try copying the *entire* data directory. You can start the server using that, but the data will be corrupted. You might need an expert to salvage something.

Again: the best is to forget about the data. If you had no backups and didn't use good passwords, the data cannot have been important.

Comment: I take over a project that had bad management and tries to save as much as possible:   I take off files from /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/base/ but, do not finds any databases in psql. is there any other files eor directory i need to take. I have checked conf files

Comment: That won't do. You need *all* files from the data directory, that is the directory above `base`. You can never recover anything from just the data files.

Comment: yes see the documentation between thx